# How to post User scripts to $window.open method in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webview, window.open, userscripts

I want to open - https://myUI:88/openURL/ (e.g.: On click of a button, it should redirect to this https://myUI:88/openURL, like it happens in payment gateway) and then, I have to pass the below user script to that:

```
getRealData('{"mailing":{"postalCode":"111","city":"NJ"},"terminal":"222"}');
```

How to achieve this in AJS 1.x?

getRealData is a public method in https://myUI:88/openURL web app

Comment: Pass the "user script" in the sense?? Do you want to send the json data to the opened window from your main window?

Comment: Yes.. and call the method - getRealData on that url (its a web app)

Comment: Is it possible to do something with data uri? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data between parent window and child window by using the window.postMessage() API.

In Parent js file :

```
var childWindow = window.open(childurl);// opens a new window and puts the reference to it in childWindow variable.

childWindow.postMessage(YourMessageJson);//the json should be stringified before sending
```

In child's js file :

```
window.addEventListener('message', receivedMessage);//attach event listener to get the event sent by postMessage from your parent.

function receivedMessage(data){ //callback function executed on receiving the message
  xhr.open(url) //The http call that you wanted to make from this page (I have just put a dummy xhr call, replace it according to your use case)

}
```

Comment: This looks good, but I have no control on my childUrl and its an existing legacy web app, which has this function - getRealData

Comment: You *WILL* not be able to call a function existing in another app without writing some code to handle the event you pass from your app. And it is also a very bad practice as it involves cross-site scripting and makes the app very vulnerable.

Comment: Is it possible to run any user script for it and make it run via tampermonkey etc, compromising security tempororily is fine for now

Comment: Nope not possible.. tamper monkey doesnot allow invoking functions on other script.

Comment: Can i run a new user script - getRealData('{"mailing":{"postalCode":"111","city":"NJ"},"terminal":"222"}'); on tampermonkey and do a window.open()? Also, currently pay = null (not sure , why, window.open returns null, even though a new window is opened)

Comment: It will be null till the time the window is completely open. Try doing a setTimeout for 5000 ms and console.log the childWindow, you will get the child's window object..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134557/discussion-between-smitha-and-bala-abhinav).